# When cloning HTML document and generating a string representation, CSS style rules in original document are not copied

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to generate a string representation of a HTML document so that I can send it to another service that will generate a cloned version of my current document for printing purposes.

The original HTML document needs to have some styles added using Javascript:

```
// create the style node
var $style = $("<style type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' />").appendTo($("head"));

// create the style rule
var rules = [];
rules.push(".bluecolor {  }");
if ($style[0].styleSheet) { // IE
    $style[0].styleSheet.cssText = rules.join(" ");
} else {
    $style[0].appendChild(document.createTextNode(rules.join(" ")));
}

// later on in the code...

// set the style rule's color to blue
var sheets = document.styleSheets;
for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    if ((sheets[i].ownerNode || sheets[i].owningElement) == $style[0]) {
        var stylesheet = sheets[i];
        var cssRules =  (stylesheet.cssRules || stylesheet.rules);
        for (var i = 0; i < cssRules.length; i++) {
            if (matches = /\.bluecolor/.exec(cssRules[i].selectorText)) {
                cssRules[i].style.color = "blue";
                cssRules[i].style.width = "10px";
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

However, when I go to clone the object, the cloned version does not have the color:blue or the width: 10px properties in the bluecolor style rule:

```
var clonedDocument = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].cloneNode(true);
```

I think this has to do with the fact that the style nodes on the original document do not get updated in Chrome/Firefox when modifying the rules via Javascript. This is not the case in IE though. (Is this a Chrome bug?) Here is a sample code that demonstrates the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/T4aCC/29/

My end goal is to generate a string representation (in Chrome) of the original document. However, I am not able to do this via cloneNode and/or the way I am updating the CSS tyles via Javascript is not correct. Any suggestions?

Comment: The only solution I saw was to manually copy the original document.styleSheets's cssRules.cssText directly into the original DOM's style element. But that seems like a hack and very cumbersome.

Comment: this whole thing looks absurdly cumbersome.  I realize certain projects can require some strange solutions, but why on earth are you using javascript for these styles?  anyway...are you attempting the "clone" before the page is fully loaded?